# Зачем нужна ссылка в названии вопроса на странице вопроса?

Tags: предложение, дизайн, stackoverflow, ссылки

САБЖ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Зачем тут ссылка? Если нужно скопировать url вопроса то это удобнее делать из  адресной строки плюс есть кнопка Поделиться. Если нужно скопировать часть названия вопроса на странице вопроса то нужно зажимать alt, это может конфликтовать с другим софтом, например когда у меня стоял ДовнлоадМастер, при выделении части текста гиперссылки открывалось окно с загрузкой по этой ссылке.
Это конечно мелочи но из таких мелочей и состоит юзабилити сайта, есть ли в этой ссылке сакральный смысл? 
Имхо там ссылка не нужна.

Comment: Пожалуйста согласуйте название и тело/метки вопроса. Вы всё же спрашиваете зачем ссылка, или предлагаете её убрать?

Comment: Есть предположение, что это связано с SEO оптимизацией стриниц.

Answer (score 4):

Это примерно как ссылка в логотипе сайта всегда ведет на главную сайта. Так и тут - в названии вопроса - "чистая" ссылка на сам вопрос.

Достаточно удобно, как для обновления страницы, так и для взятия ссылки без лишнего мусора (например, если на страничку попал по ссылке на один из ответов).

Answer (score 3):

Постоянно ей пользуюсь для обновления страницы.